# How can I display multiple UserControls inside a single Window?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, user-controls

What I'm trying to do is very simple but I might be going about doing it the wrong way. I essentially want a way to show different Views from within the same Window. An example of what I have that works right now is this:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="800"
        DataContext="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=MainPageViewModel}">
    <Grid>
        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding SelectedView}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

With the above, I can now change the UserControl by setting it to something different in SelectedView. However, I think this might violate the MVVM. Now that you have an idea of what I'm trying to do, please recommend a better way, if it exists. I'm simply trying to create different views within the application without having to spawn more windows etc.

Comment: That's pretty much how I do it, and this is the mvvm way. Selectedview would be derived class of a base view model class that implements INPC. I use a contentcontrol and create multiple datatemplates, which change the user control shown based on which viewmodel type is loaded in selectedview. One thing I don't do is bind the DataCointext of the window. I override App.xaml.cs OnStartup and manually assign DataContext to my mainwindowviewmodel

Answer (score 1):

MVVM may or may not be that way.  MVVM you set up your ViewModel to be your code and then do a resource library to tell the view that it relates to a view model.  What you are doing is just a binding.  If you are doing all your code in the code behind of the 'MainWindow' that is pretty much disobeying MVVM.

You can also create a few views and then display them I believe in different DOCKING PANELS.  I only did this before I started using MVVM and I only displayed one at a time but I would think you could do more quite easily.

XAML:

```
<DockPanel x:Name="MainDock" LastChildFill="True">
        <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top">
            <StackPanel.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF759FCB" Offset="1" />
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </StackPanel.Background>

                <Menu Background="Transparent" >
                    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <UniformGrid Rows="1"/>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
                    <MenuItem Grid.Column="0" x:Name="mnuBasic" Header="Basic Batch" Click="mnuBasic_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Grid.Column="1" x:Name="mnuImages" Header="Image List" Click="mnuFENSImages_Click" />
                    <MenuItem Grid.Column="2" x:Name="mnuReRender" Header="ReRender Batch" Click="mnuReRender_Click"/>
                </Menu>
        </StackPanel>

        <DockPanel x:Name="dockcontent" DockPanel.Dock="Right" />
    </DockPanel>
```

I would then have the portion called 'dockcontent' populate with data with menu items clicked.  Sample of the code behind to populate docking:

```
Exporter exp = new Exporter();  //constructor args if needed, this is a user control

dockcontent.Children.Clear();  // clear the dockpanel so nothing already exists
dockcontent.Children.Add(exp);  // populate the dock with my user control
```

I would think you could do this with multiple methods to make multiple images.  You could do the binding I expect directly in the XAML instead as long as your object is a view in the right context.

Just remember that excessive code behind is basically not following MVVM at all.  As the point of MVVM is to isolate your presentation from your code, not have them both together.